# Is it possible to log the values of Enums in a function?

Tags: solidity

I'm currently developing a simple prediction market test dapp to further my learning & I'm writing tests right now to check the first contract out. I wanted to make sure that I was referencing & updating certain values the correct way, so I imported Hardhat console.log so that I could log out some of the outputs. I currently have a struct and two enums, & I am able to log out the values of some of my mappings containing the struct & an enum, but console.log will not work on the others.

This is the warning I get: "Member 'log' not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(library console)."

I know that I must be trying to reference or access them wrong, and might just be using them plain wrong altogether. To that extent, can someone please explain to me how to access/set an enum value, and let me know if I'm doing it all wrong below? Are those values not able to be logged to the console for some reason? I guess I'm just confused as to what I'm really accessing here, as it's very hard for me to visualize right now. I get the aforementioned error on each of the first console.log statements in the if/else, but not the second ones (the ones that reference the struct).

Relevant code is below:

```
Result public result;

enum overUnder {
    Over,
    Under
}

enum Status {
    Win,
    Lose,
    Draw
}

struct Result {
    overUnder winner;
    overUnder loser;
}

mapping(overUnder => uint256) public bets;
mapping(address => mapping(overUnder => uint256)) public betsPerBettor;
mapping(address => mapping(overUnder => Status)) public bettorWinLoss;

function winOrLose() public {
    uint256 initialPrice = 100;
    uint256 finalPrice = 120;

    if (initialPrice > finalPrice) {
        result.winner = overUnder.Under;
        bettorWinLoss[msg.sender][overUnder.Under] = Status.Win;
        console.log("User win under status: ", bettorWinLoss[msg.sender][overUnder.Under]);
        console.log("Winners under: ", result.winner);
         } else {
            result.winner = overUnder.Over;
            bettorWinLoss[msg.sender][overUnder.Over] = Status.Win;
            console.log("User win over status: ", bettorWinLoss[msg.sender]);
            console.log("Winners over: ", result.winner);
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Update, my linter was just slow. None of the console logs are working on either side with the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Enums are represented as uint values under the hood, but you the console.log function will fail to compile unless you explicitly convert them to uint before logging.

try `console.log(uint(result.winner))` and I think that will work for you.

You'll get a number which is determined by the order defined in the enum (the first enum member = 0)